# Sync map and graph series in apache echarts

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

I am using Apache Echarts v5, and I am trying to implement a graph with a world map background.

For this, I understand the best choice is to use a "graph" serie and a "map" serie, both reading from a "geo" configuration, based in a geoJSON or the world map, which I downloaded from [here](https://geojson-maps.ash.ms/). Yet I am having a hard time figuring how to do this two things:

1. **Sync coordinates, so the elements of the graph are always in the correct places of the map.**
2. **Be able to zoom in are out both the graph and the map at the same time**.

For this I have prepared a minimal example of what I am doing. This code can be directly pasted into [any echarts online example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=map-HK) and it should work (I used other geoJson for mockup).

```
myChart.showLoading();
$.get(ROOT_PATH + '/data/asset/geo/HK.json', function (geoJson) {
  myChart.hideLoading();
  echarts.registerMap('fullMap', geoJson);
  myChart.setOption(
    option = {
      legend: {
        data: [
          {
            name: 'One',
          },
          {
            name: 'Two',
          },
          {
            name: 'Three',
          },
        ],
        bottom: '25',
        itemHeight: '10',
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: '10',
        },
        type: 'scroll',
      },
      geo: [
        {
          map: 'fullMap',
          layoutSize: '100%',
          geoIndex: 0,
        },
      ],
      series: [
        {
          type: 'graph',
          layout: 'none',
          roam: true,
          lineStyle: {
            color: 'source',
            curveness: 1e-21,
          },
          data: [
            {
              id: 'A',
              name: 'A',
              category: 0,
              x: 51.8954823121139,
              y: 0.918566971127893,
              symbol: 'rect',
            },
            {
              id: 'B',
              name: 'B',
              category: 0,
              x: 52.0742496381072,
              y: 1.22603740005249,
              symbol: 'rect',
            },
            {
              id: 'C',
              name: 'C',
              category: 0,
              x: 52.8723466202309,
              y: -0.192814484661784,
              symbol: 'rect',
            },
            {
              id: 'D',
              name: 'D',
              category: 0,
              x: 53.3688011059499,
              y: 0.0024000083847046,
              symbol: 'rect',
            },
          ],

          links: [
            {
              source: 'A',
              target: 'B',
            },
            {
              source: 'B',
              target: 'C',
            },
          ],
          categories: [
            {
              name: 'One',
            },
            {
              name: 'Two',
            },
            {
              name: 'Three',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          map: 'fullMap',
          type: 'map',
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          boundingCoords: [
            [-180, 90],
            [180, -90],
          ],
          geoIndex: 0
        },
      ],
    })
});
```

The thing is, if I try to set the "coordinateSystem" for the graph serie to "geo", the graph stops rendering, and currently the zoom only works for the graph, not the map. Moreover, I have set my map to follow coordinates with "boundingCoords", but I do not see that same setting in the graph serie.

The documentation is not very clear about this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm currently facing the exact same problem. Have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

graph on map

```
myChart.showLoading();
$.get(ROOT_PATH + '/data/asset/geo/HK.json', function (geoJson) {
  myChart.hideLoading();
  echarts.registerMap('fullMap', geoJson);
  myChart.setOption(
    (option = {
      legend: {
        bottom: '25',
        itemHeight: '10',
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: '10'
        },
        type: 'scroll'
      },
      geo: [
        {
          map: 'fullMap'
        }
      ],
      series: [
        {
          type: 'graph',
          coordinateSystem: 'geo',
          roam: true,
          lineStyle: {
            width: 3,
            curveness: 0.2
          },
          data: [
            {
              name: 'A',
              category: 0,
              value: [114.14, 22.28, 80],
              symbol: 'rect'
            },
            {
              name: 'B',
              category: 0,
              value: [114.14, 22.48, 80],
              symbol: 'rect'
            },
            {
              name: 'C',
              category: 1,
              value: [113.94, 22.28, 80],
              symbol: 'rect'
            },
            {
              name: 'D',
              category: 2,
              value: [114.44, 22.28, 80],
              symbol: 'rect'
            }
          ],
          links: [
            {
              source: 'A',
              target: 'B'
            },
            {
              source: 'B',
              target: 'C'
            }
          ],
          categories: [
            {
              name: 'One'
            },
            {
              name: 'Two'
            },
            {
              name: 'Three'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer of @ned seems to work, it was not straightforward to me understanding it. As it does not have any explanation.

I think this are the key points:

1. The map has to be registered as precondition.
2. The map has to be a JSON, taking the example of the library:

```json
{"type":"FeatureCollection","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features":[{"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[47.97822265625001,7.
...
```

3. The map has to be declared in the top level of the options with the key `geo`, selecting the map with the key `map`:

```js
options = {
...
      geo: [
        {
          map: 'world',
```

4. If you want to be able to move the map add the key `roam`:

```js
      geo: [
        {
          map: 'world',
          roam: true,
```

5. Now to plot your data over the graph it has to be under the top level key `series`. Using the key `coordianteSystem` to set up the axis, as counterintuitive you do not use `x`, `y` but the key `value` with an array of the coordinates:

```js
options = {
...
     series: [
        {
          type: 'graph',
          coordinateSystem: 'geo',
          layout: 'none',
          data: this.graphData.nodes?.map(n => {
            return {
              ...
              name: n.name,
              value: [n.x, n.y],
              ...
              },
            };
          }),
```

6. The graph data for the coordiantes has to be in `Latitude Decimal Degrees` and `Longitude Decimal Degrees`.